# How not to get repeating value in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop")
data = pd.read_csv("nifty.csv")

for i in range(9,len(data['SMA(10)'])):

    if (data['SMA(10)'][i] < data['Open(-1)'][i] and
             data['SMA(10)'][i] > data['Open'][i]):
        data['Trans'][i] = "Sell"

    elif(data['SMA(10)'][i] > data['Open(-1)'][i] and 
              data['SMA(10)'][i] < data['Open'][i]):
        data['Trans'][i] = "Buy"

    else:
        data['Trans'][i] = "Hold"
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")

print(data.head(50))
```

I dont want two buy/sell values together, instead I want hold value

Comment: Explain your input data set and the out put.

Comment: Please provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use Pandas. Use a vectorized solution. -1 for sell, 1 for buy and 0 for hold. Faster than using strings but you can replace them if you choose so.

```
data['Trans'] = np.select([((data['SMA(10)'] < data['Open(-1)']) & (data['SMA(10)'] > data['Open(-1)'])),
                           ((data['SMA(10)'] > data['Open(-1)']) & (data['SMA(10)'] < data['Open(-1)']))],
                           (-1, 1), 0)
```